# How do I tell my teacher what I had to do in my homework?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple

I don't know how to describe my homework task, I mean I don't know which tense to use. 
For example:

1. I have done my homework, where **I had to** review requirements, execute test cases and report a defects
2. I have done my homework, where **I have to** review requirements, execute test cases and report a defects

Which variant is right?
Feel free to provide your variants. I would be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct variant would be :

> I have done my homework which consisted of reviewing requirements, executing test cases and reporting defects.

Your variants are incorrect, because you don't use "a" before plural ("defects"). Where is the wrong word for homework, the correct one could be "in which". The part "I had to" is correct, and "I have to" is not.

Comment: Does it mean my variants are incorrect?

Comment: @Yamis - yes. I will add in my answer why.

Comment: Why don't you use 'that' instead 'which'?